# training not starting in botfront

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm trying to train my model with new intent and entities but I see an error called "string indices must be integers" as you can see:

[image: string indices must be integers]

Please help with a quick fix. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is this.
you need to disable the gazette in the pipeline.

Go to settings up! in NLU pipeline, remove  name: rasa_addons.nlu.components.gazette.Gazette

Thanks

Comment: yes I was able to solve it, thanks for confirming the solution though.